# How to debug a Python module in Visual Studio Code's launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My question may seem simple but, I have a module that I launch in a terminal like this:

```sh
python -m my_module.my_file
```

How do I debug this in Visual Studio Code?

I have this in my `launch.json` ([documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python))

```
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"pythonPath": "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\simulec\\python.exe",
"args": [
   "-m",
   "my_module.my_file",
]
```

If I don't set the `program` option or if I set it to `""` I get "File does not exist" Error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 58):

Actually, there is a very simple option to do this I found by accident while trying to edit the `launch.json` file.

```
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"pythonPath": "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\simulec\\python.exe",
"module": "my_module.my_file",
```

**Simply specify the module in the module key `"module": "my_module.my_file"`**

The `-m` is not useful any more.

Comment: Thank you! I had a hard time finding this. After reading the the docs more carefully I found this option is mentioned under python debugging: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types

Comment: thanks it's working! However, the relaive imported packages can't be found anymore even I set "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" in launch.json.  Any Solution?

Comment: @zheyuanWang A year too late, but I figured out the solution for relative imports. You must also set the property "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}".

Comment: @Alecg_O I don't understand. @zheyuanWang says that it didn't work with `cwd: ${workspaceFolder}`; and your solution is setting `cwd: ${workspaceFolder}`? Is there a typo or something?

Comment: @zheyuanWang If you are within the package directory, just add `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/.."` to your `launch.json` file to change to its parent directory. In this way, Vscode should see you package directory.

Answer (score 12):

In a terminal like this: `python -m xyz abc.z3`

(Please make sure you are opening "the root folder of your project").

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "xyz",
            "args": [
                "abc.z3"
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To add slightly to [dzada's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102228/how-to-debug-a-python-module-in-visual-studio-codes-launch-json/46158021#46158021), which helped me a lot, a Visual Studio Code variable can be used to make this general for debugging any file that is in your module.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "my_module.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is probably what you want to do.

Comment: This had worked for me on a local install but isn't working in a docker container. Any ideas - do I need to trigger launch.json after I edit it?

Comment: @mmann1123 does this help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python

Answer (score 6):

The answer from @dzada was a bit confusing for me so I tried to rephrase it and add more clarification.

To debug a module in file called `script_file.py` that exists in a package called `packagex` with structure like the following:

```
Project_Folder
   packagex
      script_file.py
```

Your configuration in the `launch.json` file should looks like the following

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: any name like script_file",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "packagex.script_file"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

After some searching, I found that the config can be generalized for any module by the use of [the Command Variable extension](https://github.com/rioj7/command-variable#commands). Assuming that the your workspace folder is the one containing the package, the following configuration would work for any module:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",
    "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "module",
            "type": "pythonExperimental",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "my_package.my_module.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned it already, for me in 2024 this works:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The structure of your code should be:

```
your_project/
│
├── .vscode/
│   ├── launch.json
│
└── (other project files and folders)
```