# How to run python in Visual Studio Code as a main module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to run python in Visual Studio Code as a **main module**?

From the command line I would use the `-m` switch, like

```
python -m program.py
```

I need this to make relative imports work.

Is there something I could add to the `launch.json` file?

If this isn't possible, I maybe need to do something with `runpy` [see python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html), but it would be nice if vscode can do this.

**Edit:**

For the moment I use, as a workaround, an extra `run.py` file which I place outside the package I want to run. Then configure vscode to run that file:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/../run.py"
```

From `run.py` I import the package and call its entry-point function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation for debugging a module can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types

All you need to do is:

- Select the `Python: Module` debug cofiguration in VS Code
- Edit the `launch.json` and locate the `Python: Module` config section and replace the value for the setting `module` with the module name, e.g. `program`

Comment: This is helpful for debugging. But what about when you just want to run the python file without the debugger?

Comment: Also, do you have to manually change this every time you want to debug a different file?

Comment: Additional clarification: the configuration in `launch.json` is also used to run without debugging. To me, the documentation is a bit misleading as it refers to debugging only. Hence, if you only want to run your code without debugging, you also need to set the configuration in `launch.json`.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: app",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "module_name.app",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you expand more where you got `module_name.app` from? I want to launch my debugger from the same dir every time but am unsure how to do that

Answer (score 4):

Following this answer worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74002325/21195101

Uses the [Command Variable VSCode Extension](https://github.com/rioj7/command-variable#commands) to set the module name automatically. This way regardless of whether you run the file directly or as an import, it behaves the same way.

```
{
    "name": "Python: As Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true
}
```

Comment: In my case, VS code throws the error:
**command 'extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension' not found**