# How to run a file in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am learning PHP and I have decided to use VS Code. Is there any way I can run the files without a compiler? I have looked in the output section but nothing is there.

Comment: PHP is interpreted, not compiled. You need the PHP interpreter on your machine before you can execute it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python in Visual Studio Code as a main module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164843/how-to-run-python-in-visual-studio-code-as-a-main-module)