# How to make VScode launch.json for a Python module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch, vscode-debugger

I'm researching [self-supervised machine learning code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/swav).

And I have wanted to debug the code with `python debugger` not `pdb.set_trace()`.
This is python command for ubuntu terminal.

```bash
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=1 main_swav.py \
--data_path /dataset/imagenet/train \
--epochs 400 \
--base_lr 0.6 \
--final_lr 0.0006 \
--warmup_epochs 0 \
--batch_size 8 \
--size_crops 224 96 \
--nmb_crops 2 6 \
--min_scale_crops 0.14 0.05 \
--max_scale_crops 1. 0.14 \
--use_fp16 true \
--freeze_prototypes_niters 5005 \
--queue_length 380 \
--epoch_queue_starts 15\
--workers 10
```

In order to debug the code with VScode, I tried to revise launch.json like below as referring [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102228/how-to-debug-a-python-module-in-visual-studio-codes-launch-json)

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "module": "torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=1 main_swav.py",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["--data_path", "/dataset/imagenet/train"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I knew this would not work...

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: `args` is used to pass command line arguments along to the app being launched. `program` is used to specify the python file. View [debug python in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) before you start debugging.

Comment: Note that currently (2024): `"type" : "python"` is deprecated. Use "debugpy" instead: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_module

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Specify the module you want to run with** `"module": "torch.distributed.launch"`

You can ignore the `-m` flag. Put everything else under the `args` key.

**Note:** Make sure to include `--nproc_per_node` and the name of file (`main_swav.py`) in the list of arguments

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "module": "torch.distributed.launch",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "--nproc_per_node", "1", 
                "main_swav.py",
                "--data_path", "/dataset/imagenet/train",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Read more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_module

Comment: Any update in this for the newer `torchrun`?

Comment: @aviator set your module to [`torch.distributed.run`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8a744c31d3c5194b4850869a112d94912c1e08b4/setup.py#L968)

Comment: @ringo That would cast away the benefit from `torchrun` and accompany efforts setting various distribution related environment variables. Why not just run as `program:{torchrun_path}`?

Comment: I don't think so. `torchrun` is just a simple Python script file that runs `torch.distributed.run.main`, and running `torch.distributed.run` as a module does the same thing.

Comment: If you have the `program` entry (e.g.,  `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py"`) remove it and add It in the `args` after `"--nproc_per_node", "1",`

Comment: @aviator replace ```module``` with ```program```, like this:
```"program": "/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/your_env/bin/torchrun"```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of my `launch.json` that I use to debug Python modules.

It has an additional configuration to debug "current file" (not as module) which is useful to keep.

```
{
linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Module",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "path.to.module",
      "args": ["run_example --arg <arg>"],
      "justMyCode": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This would replicate a terminal command to run a Python module like so:

```
python -m path.to.module run_example --arg <arg>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the new torchrun (Torch 2.0.1) here is launch.json:

- "module" is no longer used
- the full path to torchrun is needed (at least for me)

```
{
    "name": "working",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/home/user_x/anaconda3/envs/env_y/bin/torchrun",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "args": [
        "example_chat_completion.py",
        "--nproc_per_node", "1",
        "--ckpt_dir", "llama-2-7b-chat/",
        "--tokenizer_path", "tokenizer.model",
        "--max_seq_len", "512",
        "--max_batch_size", "6",
    ]
},
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.