# How to debug the llama2 inference command with Vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, llama

I am trying to run the LLAMA2 inference script (shown below) with vscode debugging mode:

```
    torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_text_completion.py \
    --ckpt_dir models/7B-Chat \
    --tokenizer_path tokenizer.model \
    --max_seq_len 128 --max_batch_size 4
```

Before this, I can successfully run it with my command line interface, which shows my python environment is correct.

I have tried these two debug configs below:

1. ```
    {
        "name": "Python: run_llama2_inference",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "torchrun",
        "args": [
            "--nproc_per_node=1",
            "example_chat_completion.py",
            "--ckpt_dir=models/7B-Chat/",
            "--tokenizer_path=tokenizer.model",
            "--max_seq_len=512",
            "--max_batch_size=4",
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    },
   ```

   Corresponding Error Messsage: "No module named torchrun"
2. ```
    {
        "name": "Python: run_llama2_inference",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "torch.distributed.launch",
        "args": [
            "--use-env",
            "example_chat_completion.py",
            "--nproc_per_node=1",
            "--ckpt_dir=models/7B-Chat/",
            "--tokenizer_path=tokenizer.model",
            "--max_seq_len=512",
            "--max_batch_size=4",
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "env":
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    },
   ```

   Corresponding Error Messsage: "Could not consume arg: --nproc_per_node=1"

Both configs do not work as expected. I would like to seek the advice from online experts. Appreciate your ideas or advice in advance!

Comment: See here: [debug pytorch multiple GPUs in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518928/how-to-make-vscode-launch-json-for-a-python-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `"program"` field to specify the Python script you want to run (`example_text_completion.py`), and pass the rest of the arguments using the `"args"` field.

Here's an example of how you can modify your launch configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "Python: run_llama2_inference",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/example_chat_completion.py",
    "args": [
        "--ckpt_dir=models/7B-Chat/",
        "--tokenizer_path=tokenizer.model",
        "--max_seq_len=512",
        "--max_batch_size=4",
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi MingJie, thanks for replying. May I ask how can I add the "torchrun" in the debugger?

Comment: I have tried a few combinations but all failed. I guess the "torchrun" command can only run from terminal rather than debugger mode, but would like to seek advice from python or torch experts.

Comment: @Yneedtobeserious I‘m sorry that I missed it. The `torchrun` command is a utility provided by PyTorch for running PyTorch scripts, and it's not a Python module. It cannot be used directly in the debugger configuration in VSCode.

Comment: thank you so much. That's what I guessed. appreciate your advice!