# Vscode debug custom command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a python project and a command which runs the project which I'd like to debug.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "pipenv run python -m myproject.mymodule --count 500",
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work, but my goal is to run the command from above and have it catch breakpoints and step through, etc.

I have tried setting it as a `preLaunchTask` with a `tasks.json` file, but when I use this, it does not let me use the debugging features for the command (i.e. it would run the command as expected, but it would not trigger breakpoints).

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You don't have `"` at the end of the command

Comment: just a typo, apologies, not the issue though

Comment: [How to debug a Python module in Visual Studio Code's launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102228/how-to-debug-a-python-module-in-visual-studio-codes-launch-json)

Comment: Can you describe in detail the operation you are debugging? At the same time, provide a case of reproducible problems https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this, after doing some more research, I found this works:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "myproject.mymodule",
            "args": ["--count", 500]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is equivalent to running to command `pipenv run python -m myproject.mymodule --count 500` and debugging features such as breakpoints are being triggered.